# Местоимения. Пока не про нас, но есть вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, нормы-поведения

Выложили официальные [требования по использованию местоимений](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/309650) и лично мне они не нравятся. Переводить их все я здесь не буду, но в них явно есть интересные моменты (оригинальные англоязычные варианты можно найти в комментариях в разметке вопроса, улучшения перевода приветствуются):

> **Обязан ли я использовать местоимения, с которыми я не знаком или которые мне не нравятся (например, неоместоимения типа xe, zir, ne...)**
>
> Да, если индивид об этом явно заявил.

> **Что если я считаю грамматически неверным использовать некоторые местоимения (например they/them по отношению к одному человеку)?**
>
> Если эти местоимения заявлены индивидом, ты обязан это уважать и использовать их. Грамматическая корректность уступает праву человека на самоидентификацию.

> **Если мне неудобно использовать конкретное местоимение, могу ли я просто избегать его?**
>
> Мы просим всех использовать все заявленные местоимения в той же степени, как вы обычно делаете при письме. Явное избегание чьего-то местоимения из-за того, что вам оно неудобно, это способ отказа в самоидентификации и нарушение Кодекса Поведения.

> **Как это применимо к сайтам на других языках?**
>
> На данный момент, хотя требование быть внимательным и уважительным ко всем гендерным вариантам применимо ко всем нашим сообществам, конкретные требования по местоимениям применимы только на англоязычных сайтах. Когда мы определим лучшие практики для других языков, мы поработаем с соответствующими сообществами и обновим требования для их языков.

> **Теперь все сообщения надо писать гендерно-нейтрально? Следует ли редактировать старые сообщения?**
>
> Главная цель изменения — использование правильных местоимений при обращении к другим членам сообщества. Однако писать сообщения на гендерно-нейтральном языке — это отлично и всячески привествуется, потому что делает сообщество доступным большему числу людей. Если вы пишете или редактируете сообщение и можете сделать его гендерно-нейтральным без изменения смысла, то это приветствуется.

---

В соответствии с этими правилами на англоязычных сайтах мы можем потребовать использовать по отношению к себе любые местоимения. [А как насчёт русскоязычных?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/334931/309650)

**Что если мы все начнём требовать называть себя русскими местоимениями вместо английских?** Может быть таким образом мы сможем показать абсурдность всей этой идеи? Ведь мы всё-таки на сайте для программистов, где ни пол, ни раса, ни национальность не играют никакой роли.

Comment: Не спешите вы так. Чуть позже, думаю, кто-нибудь официальный анонс у нас сделает по теме (:

Comment: Так-так так. А как выполнить заявление? Т.е я в начале поста на enSO обозначить, что бы ко мне обращались как "Соленый огурчик" и после этого они должны будут писать Mr.Соленый огурчик?

Comment: @iluxa1810 вроде как "Соленый огурчик" использовать нельзя, только местоимения. Да и я не понял, где конкретно нужно указывать местоимение. В профиле я не нашел такой информации. Писать это в каждом посте - ну такое.

Comment: @AntonSorokin если к вам обратились в комментарии с местоимением, которое вас задевает, то вы там можете об этом в комментах написать и указать то, как к вам обращаться. В сами вопросы/ответы это тащить не надо.

Comment: @Suvitruf хм, а я думал сделают отдельное поле в профиле, где можно написать местоимение по которому нужно обращаться. И если кликнуть на профиль, то можно увидеть как обращаться к человеку.

Comment: @AntonSorokin такое предложение было. Не знаю, будет ли оно реализовано.

Comment: Судя по количеству голосов и комментариям, эти нововведения большинству и в англоязычном сообществе не очень нравятся. Думаю, что стоит пока высказаться всем, кто хочет в указанной теме, голосом, ответом или комментарием

Comment: Ну вот, теперь у нас анонимки!

Comment: Объясните мне, почему никто никогда не предлагает в качестве гендернейтрального использовать it.

Comment: @bipll У местоимения "it" есть определённое значение: предмет "без души", предмет без "человеческой" составляющей. Эта граница особенна заметна при описании животных: в английском для них используются как одушевлённые, так и неодушевлённые местоимения в зависимости от контекста.

Comment: @Kyubey Да, а у местоимения he — тот, кто родился мужчиной. Почему-то определенные значения уже не так хорошо работают.

Comment: @demonplus большинству вообще по барабану эти изменения, и их непосредственно это никогда не коснётся.

Comment: [чтоб понять мне Приведите пример / (?<=<) (\w+) /x нужно привести пример к регулярному выражению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1037277/%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-w-x-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb). Комментарий к вопросу: `я теперь понял` (c) `marina`. Уже про нас... :(

Comment: "Грамматическая корректность уступает праву человека на самоидентификацию." - шта?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Что если мы все начнём требовать называть себя русскими местоимениями вместо английских? Может быть таким образом мы сможем показать абсурдность всей этой идеи?

Боюсь что навряд ли это сработает. Такая акция скорее будет расценена как троллинг.

Вся эта идея основана на том, что определенная группа лиц физически и психологически страдает от того что к ним не обращаются по предпочитаемому им местоимению. Предполагается что эти лица жаловались на подобное обращение администрации. Изменения в нормах, как бы они ни были топорны, имеют целью защитить их.

Будет достаточно сложно защитить позицию: «Я страдаю от того что на англоязычном сайте ко мне обращаются не по-русски». Во-первых, потому что это явная ложь. Во-вторых, потому что многие наши участники раньше общались на англоязычных сайтах сети и, насколько я знаю, никогда не выражали претензии к местоимениям ни здесь, ни где бы то ни было. Лживые предложения будут справедливо расценены как троллинг.

Еще один вариант, что с кириллическими местоимениями согласятся, но никто на них не будет обращать внимания, так же, впрочем, как и на остальные предпочитаемые местоимения. Необходимость в местоимениях третьего лица возникает редко. Бунт никого не зацепит.

Ну и, конечно, не стоит исключать самый идиотский результат из возможных: если эта липа пройдет и компания действительно начнет всерьез требовать чтобы желающих называли «он/она/on/ona». В этом случае желающим придется разыгрывать спектакль до конца: писать слезные статьи в блог компании, давать интервью, спорить с другими участниками, жаловаться на них, старательно переключать язык ввода. Иначе получится уже не просто личный троллинг, а целая кампания по унижению, совершаемая организованной группой лиц.

Это предложение немногим отличается от [предложения абсурдных местоимений](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes/334931#334908) (я хочу чтобы меня называли соленым огурчиком). Модераторы уже предлагают такие предложения отмечать тревогами.

### А как насчет нас

В русском языке ситуация усложняется тем, что есть грамматический род, в том числе у неодушевленных предметов. Так что применить к нам местоимения будет несколько сложнее. Например, если я пишу:

> Автору нужно перезагрузить базу данных. Она у него в некорректном состоянии.

То «у него» относится к слову «автор», а не к автору и его полу (биологическому или психологическому). Есть слабая надежда, что при адаптации учтут этот момент.

Вообще для того чтобы нарушить новые нормы при нормальном использовании сайта должна произойти целая цепочка маловероятных событий (встретить трансгендера, вступить с ним в общение, увидеть предпочтение, обратиться к нему в третьем лице, услышать протест, отказаться править/удалять свои посты). Изменения могут затронуть разве что завсегдатаев англоязычных чатов. Даже если их не откатят, изменения скорее несут показательный характер (virtue signalling), чем практический.

Comment: Всё зависит от практик. Во внешнем мире успешно живут пастафарианцы и фоткаются на паспорты в религиозных одеяниях. Однако это не означает, что модераторы на SE будут следовать духу закона и свободе самовыражения. Ничто не мешает объявить троллями всех, кто выбрал местоимения не из официально одобренного списка нео-местоимений. / Аргумент "что же вы раньше молчали", к слову, не совсем корректен. Раньше молчали, потому что нас угнетали (возможно, мы даже не осознавали этого).

Comment: Подозреваю, что количество вставляющих в свои сообщения нео-метоимения заметно вырастет. Если не дадут пользоваться местоимением "солёный огурчик", то протестующие просто будут играть по правилам и вставлять официально одобренные местоимения. Мне кажется, протестного духа на это хватит. Но суть одна: реальных трансгендеров среди всего этого хаоса будет мало.

Comment: Побуду занудой: это не в русском языке род доведён до абсурда (он наследовал его из старославянского и так далее до позднего праиндоевропейского языка), а в других языках произошло слияние.

Comment: @Kyubey Пастафарианцы хороший пример. Но да, не уверен что компания и модераторы спокойно отнесутся к протестному движению. И не уверен что протестное движение будет достаточно большим. Возможностей для протеста немного.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Не знал что в праиндоевропейском у существительных есть род. Спасибо!

Comment: А откуда нам знать страдает ли SJW на самом деле от того, что к ним не так обращается или они намеренно вредят большинству? Это так же не обосновано, как то, что кто-то страдает, что к нему обращаются не по русскому местоимению.

Comment: Не понятно про сложность с русской спецификой. В вашем примере "Она у него в корректном состоянии" прекрасно понятно к чему относиться "она", а к кому "него".

Comment: @Cerbo Сложнее сказать что «у него» неправильное местоимение, не соответствующее полу автора. Для сравнения, в английском «he» и «she» в основном относятся к людям и их полу.

Comment: @defaultlocale Если бы речь шла о женщине, то было бы "у нее". Что за проблемы тут?

Comment: @Cerbo Я полагаю что будет «у него» независимо от автора, даже если автор неизвестен. «У нее» звучит несогласованно, так же как «опытная автор». Но признаюсь это моё интуитивное понимание, найти какое-либо правило у меня не получилось. Могу сказать лишь то, что из примера я не могу сделать вывод о поле автора.

Comment: @defaultlocale Вы говорите об обобщенном или неопределенном упоминании. Тут будут действовать правила русского языка в котором по-умолчанию используется мужской род, кстати как и в большинстве индо-европейских языков где есть грамматический род. Не вижу тут проблем.

Comment: @defaultlocale, https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/suschestvitelnyie-obschego-roda-71399.html . Вообще, вследствие глобальной феминизации, видимо, будет всё больше таких слов.

Answer (score 15):

Я хотел ограничиваться комментариями, но моя мысль, к сожалению, не помещается в них.

Мне хотелось бы обсудить причины раздражения обычных пользователей. На это есть несколько фундаментальных причин, и далеко не все из них можно заткнуть непробиваемым аргументом "ты просто трансфоб".

---

#### Местоимения и обращения

Оценки количества трансгендеров среди всего населения варьируются от 0.1%<sup>[[1]](http://www.istat.it/it/files/2012/05/Notametodologica.pdf?title=Popolazione+omosessuale+nella+societ%C3%A0+-+17%2Fmag%2F2012+-+Nota+metodologica.pdf)</sup> до 0.58%<sup>[[2]](http://williamsinstitute.law.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/How-Many-Adults-Identify-as-Transgender-in-the-United-States.pdf)</sup>. Подавляющее большинство трансгендеров (79.5%) предпочитает "singular they", традиционные "he" и "she" используются в сумме двумя третями (30.8% и 29.0%), 10.3% предпочитает избегать местоимений (в опросе можно было выбрать несколько вариантов, поэтому сумма больше 100%).<sup>[[3]](https://gendercensus.com/post/183832246805/gender-census-2019-the-full-report-worldwide)</sup> Самое популярное местоимение "xe" предпочитают использовать только 7.2% из опрошенных трансгендеров, 9% предпочитают местоимения, отличные от "he", "she" и "they".

Итого, правило использовать нео-местоимения касается только 0.009%–0.05% людей, то есть где-то одного человека на 10 000. Кроме того, в опросе не было вопроса "оскорбит ли вас использование традиционного местоимения?" Думаю, подавляющее большинство людей относится с пониманием к окружающим, которые не в курсе языковых нововведений от LGBTQA+, поэтому даже это число не отражает тех, кто пострадает от, например, простой рекомендации по возможности использовать "singular they".

Что мне кажется странным — это фокус на местоимениях. У людей есть и предпочтения по обращениям Mr/Ms/Prof/etc. Среди трансгендеров процент предпочитающих обращение "Mx" составляет 31.3%, что в 3 раза превышает число трансгендеров, предпочитающих какие-либо нео-местоимения.<sup>[3]</sup> Данное предпочтение полностью игнорируется вводимыми правилами, и мне кажется, что это неправильно, особенно учитывая, что подобные обращения гораздо более уместны при общении, чем местоимения от третьего лица. (Я не знаток этикета, но меня поправляли, когда я употреблял местоимения третьего лица в присутствии обсуждаемого человека.)

---

#### Свобода слова

Соединённые Штаты Америки имеют обширную историю, касающуюся свободы слова. Свобода слова — это часть первой поправки к Конституции Соединённых Штатов.<sup>[[4]](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/first_amendment)</sup> Свобода слова также распространяется на запрет "compelled speech"<sup>[[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compelled_speech)</sup>, когда людям предписывается говорить то, с чем они несогласны (то есть это не запрет говорить запрещённое, это обязанность говорить положенное). Логично, что "compelled speech" в правилах<sup>[[6]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes)</sup> встречает сопротивление.

Обвинение в троллинге всех, кто запрашивает использование местоимений, которые не попали в один из неофициальных списков из десятков нео-местоимений<sup>[[7]](http://pronoun.is/all-pronouns)</sup>, вообще говоря, некорректно. Аналогичное сопротивление встречала и Церковь Летающего Макаронного Монстра, однако на данный момент церковь имеет официальный статус в нескольких юрисдикциях<sup>[[8]](https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-news-from-elsewhere-35112484)</sup>.

---

#### Ограничения вводимых правил

Если говорить только о трансгендерах, то требование вписываться в некоторые неофициальные списки может быть рационально, но предпочтения об обращениях в третьем лице выходят за рамки трансгендеров и местоимений. Например, в среде сообщества фурри часто считается неполиткорректным использовать слова вроде "люди", причём это слово может раздражать кого угодно от териантропов до фурри-фанов.<sup>[9]</sup> Предпочтения о местоимениях тоже имеются, хотя они и не оформляются официально и не произносятся сразу после приветствия.

Подобные предпочтения не вписываются в новые правила. Более того, если модераторы получат официальный список разрешённых местоимений и прочих требований, то просьбы, которые могут быть рациональны для фуррей, будут сочтены модераторами троллингом, несмотря на искренность просьб. Это неприемлемо.

---

#### Реакция сообщества

Реакция сообщества однозначна: на данный момент FAQ по вводимым изменениям собрал более 600 минусов на Meta Stack Exchange.<sup>[[10]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes)</sup> Если подобная реакция будет продолжаться, то вместо толератности и понимания трансгендеры и прочие люди, которым сложно найти понимание, встретят больше негативной реакции в свой адрес, а не меньше. Модераторы могут пытаться пресекать троллинг, но когда правила искусственно создают негативную атмосферу противостояния, это всё равно будет чувствоваться.

Администрации следует пересмотреть свой подход к обновлению правил, чтобы большинство пользователей стало относиться к трансгендерам лучше, а не хуже.

---

#### Ссылки

1. http://www.istat.it/it/files/2012/05/Notametodologica.pdf?title=Popolazione+omosessuale+nella+societ%C3%A0+-+17%2Fmag%2F2012+-+Nota+metodologica.pdf
2. http://williamsinstitute.law.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/How-Many-Adults-Identify-as-Transgender-in-the-United-States.pdf
3. https://gendercensus.com/post/183832246805/gender-census-2019-the-full-report-worldwide
4. https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution/first_amendment
5. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compelled_speech
6. [‎https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes) (Q9, Q10, Q11)
7. http://pronoun.is/all-pronouns
8. https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-news-from-elsewhere-35112484
9. ОРИСС
10. [‎https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes)

Comment: Среди моих знакомых просто по статистике должны быть несколько геев/лесбиянок (не уверен о трансах :)). Но я ни о ком из них этого не знаю просто потому что люди об этом не говорят и не требуют уважать какие-то их права. Мы прекрасно уживаемся, не трогая темы, которые не должны выходить за рамки, гм, семьи. Это вкратце о моем отношении к самому явлению.

Comment: О правах: меня оскорбляет требование писать о человеке "оно" - я считаю это оскорблением. Поэтому при таком требовании я прекращу общение и занесу такого человека в личный черный список. Правила же не могут требовать от меня продолжать общение с человеком, поведение которого я лично считаю оскорбительным как минимум для себя лично? P.S. Меня лично задевает, когда ко мне обращаются на "ты", особенно когда это человек, явно младший и по возрасту, и по знаниям, но не по нахальству :). Я это просто игнорирую. Почему трансы не могут вести себя так же - как написано в правилах - доброжелательно?...

Comment: @Harry "Поэтому при таком требовании я прекращу общение" Да, на данный момент это лучшее решение в случае возникновения такой ситуации. Ну или обращаться всегда по нику.

Comment: @Harry Вариант "[не спрашивай, не говори](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9,_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8)" — это прогресс по отношению к заведомо негативному отношению, но его следует рассматривать не как предел мечатний, а как промежуточный компромиссный вариант, пока в обществе нормализуется отношение к меньшинствам. Скажем, вариант подходит для старшего поколения с закостенелыми взглядами.

Comment: При "не спрашивай, ни говори" девушка не может поделиться радостью "я встретила девушку своей мечты" на перекуре, парни [не могут держаться за руки при прогулке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoEwXT8Sfb8), я уж молчу про юридические ограничения типа запрета посещения супруга в реанимации и отсутствии приоритета при наследовании. Будучи гетеросексуалом, увидеть все эти проблемы довольно сложно, поэтому надо чутче прислушиваться к мнению меньшинств. Мои свободолюбивые взгляды простираются далеко за пределы вопросов пола, но, похоже, я до принятия подобных взглядов обществом не доживу.

Comment: @Harry Я считаю, что местоимение "вы" — это уродование русского языка, притащенное Петром из-за бугра. Особенно мерзко местоимение "Вы" с большой буквы. Деление на "ты" и "вы" создаёт искусственные границы между людьми и разводит ритуалы на пустом месте. Грамматически это тоже генерирует проблемы: "вы" множественного числа, даже когда человек один, поэтому возникает путаница. На РуСО принято обращение на "вы", к сожалению, поэтому приходится адаптироваться. / Что касается "оно", то просьбы использовать это местоимение у нас не распространены, вроде.

Comment: @Kyubey Не сомневаюсь, более того, вижу корреляцию между отношением к, гм, альтернативным полам :) и отсутствием вежливости. Как и обещал, вношу вас в личный черный список и общение завершаю :)

Comment: @Suvitruf Как сказано в FAQ и доказано на примере Моники, избегание использования нео-местоимений и предпочтение ников запрещено.

Comment: @Harry Вы поосторожнее с подобными заявлениями. "Вношу вас в чёрный список" — это проявление недружелюбности, что запрещено даже необновлённым CoC. На данный момент невежливость проявляете исключительно вы.

Comment: Сделайте и вы то же самое, пожалуйста. Я не буду считать это проявлением недружелюбия. Но чем дальше, тем больше я понимаю @VladD, которого атмосфера на RuSO заколебала и заставила de facto уйти отсюда. Мне бы не хотелось, чтобы причиной моего ухода был вопрос об альтернативно одаренных альтернативно ориентированных. Но я готов и к этому, потому что следующим недалеким шагом всеобщей толерантности будет https://forum.pravda.com.ua/?topic=852164.0

Comment: @Harry Шутка по ссылке в меру смешная и демонстрирует некоторые проблемные аспекты подходов, из-за которых особо активных борцов заклеймили "SJW", но если вы следите за новостями, то понимаете, что насильное предоставление сервиса бизнесом, особенно в ущерб другим клиентам — это не более, чем преувеличение, страшилка. / Влад ушёл совершенно не из-за насаждения политкорректности, к слову. Он вообще живёт в самом центре Европы, где толератность (настоящая, а не лицемерная) — это норма, а не исключение. Да и текущее обновление СоС — капля в море, хоть и привлекшая много внимания.

Comment: Статистика по US, аргументы "их мало", свобода слова в США, singular they и фурри - это, конечно, интересно, но какое отношение это имеет к адаптации изменений в правилах к русскоязычным сайтам? Вариант "мы на мете решили, что ваши изменения - не изменения, и они никому, даже у вас реально не нужны, т.к. реальной проблем нет" (я правильно понял суть ответа?), очевидно, не прокатит :)

Comment: @Harry по поводу вы-ты - я лично оказался в ситуации (на ruSO) когда другой участник (старый и заслуженный) заявил, что обращение на "вы" его обижает :) так что не все так однозначно.

Comment: @PashaPash Так как администрация не запостила официальный перевод FAQ по изменениям в CoC, то я воспользовался этим топиком для обсуждения темы в целом. Текст вопроса, если по-чесноку, тоже не адаптацию обсуждает. :) Ответ не урезается в одно предложение. Там несколько ортогональных мыслей, а не аргументация одной позиции.

Comment: @Kyubey это если они смогут доказать, что вы используете ники для обхода правила. Как они это будут доказывать? Без понятия, если честно...

Comment: @Harry среди моих знакомых есть геи и лесбиянки. Примечательно, что они как раз хотят быть обычной частью общества, а не отдельной. Для них введение отдельных местоимений выглядит как установка питьевых фонтанчиков для негров.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev когда я это написал на MSE (что меньшинства "наоборот не хотят выделяться"), меньшинства зафлагали мой пост и его удалили. Видимо, разница менталитетов (:

Comment: @Harry, со мной вроде разговариваешь?)

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет. Только переписываюсь...

Comment: @Harry, а это одно и то же)))

Answer (score 6):

Меня вот что волнует.

Допустим, пользователь не является носителем языка, пока плохо знает его и банально по этой причине не может грамотно употреблять даже старые добрые местоимения: he/she/it, он/она/оно. Тем более он не способен правильно употребить все эти xe, zir, ne. Не станет ли это причиной минусования, а то и бана, этого пользователя?

До сего момента, насколько я могу судить по своим ощущениям, на en.so довольно терпимо относились к сообщениям на неграмотном английском, будь то вопрос/ответ/комментарий.
Но с этой толерастией, боюсь, ситуация может измениться в худшую сторону.

Кстати, на ru.so, на мой взгляд, к сообщениям на плохом русском языке, сделанным пользователями с никами явно из республик Средней Азии, Кавказа и т. п., относятся гораздо хуже.

Comment: Ждите исправления вашего вопроса из-за слова, которое "может быть воспринято" не так)

Comment: Только вообще-то я тут в принципе редко встречал вопросы на сильно неграмотном русском.

Answer (score 0):

Я всецело поддерживаю эту идею.
Если разрешно вводить новые местоимения типа xir, то мы можем потребовать использования кириллических местоимений.

Предлагаю следующие шаблоны:

> Preferred pronouns: он, его, него, ему, нему, им, ним, о нём.

и

> Preferred pronouns: она, её, неё, ей, ней, ею, ней, нею.

Comment: Ура, бьем противника его же оружием!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334964/152799

Comment: @VladD но мы ведь тут в одном сообществе. Про каких противников речь? )=

Comment: А я -- не поддерживаю эту идею. Как участник сайта и как человек, разговаривающий на русском языке считаю подобные флэшмобы позорящими русских на метасайте. Поставил минус.

Comment: +1 за красивую идею, -1 потому что сомневаюсь, что такой бунт что-то даст. :) Пост по ссылке сами удалили, или это модераторы меты лютуют?

Comment: А потом ruSO закроют целиком за стёб и нетолерантность.)

Comment: Как вам уже заметили в комментариях к ответу на MSE, пдобный список вводит в заблуждение, потому что в английском меньше форм местоимений. Кроме того, разница между "его" и "него" явно плохо транслируется в другой язык. Для простоты советую начать с "он, его". Впрочем, можете вставить инструкцию по шести падежам.

Comment: Этот комментарий содержит нападки на человека или группу людей, я удалил его. Прошу участников придерживаться установленных правил общения.

Comment: @Suvitruf на деле же в разных.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , кто еще мог его удалить? Посмотрите вокруг %)

Comment: @Suvitruf: Про тех, кто пытается продавить идею о местоимениях, разумеется.

Comment: А где здесь позор? Если английским LGBT можно выбирать местоимения, то и русским тоже должно быть можно.

Comment: @VladD никто русским не запрещает выбирать местоимения на русском сайте.

Comment: Не пройдет - права русских не сравнить по значимости с правами трансов :)

Comment: @Suvitruf: Развейте вашу мысль. А на английском сайте нам нельзя выбирать местоимения? А английским участникам на русском? (Не стоит мне говорить, что они к нам никогда не придут, приходили не раз.)

Comment: @VladD на ruSO всё на русском, на enSO всё на английском. Это моя позиция как участника и как модератора.

Comment: @Suvitruf: То есть если к нам в чат или на сайт зайдёт какой-нибудь zir, мы всё ещё можем называть его «он»? Это вы говорите как модератор? Как это соотносится с CoC?

Comment: @VladD пока что я могу сказать, что это моя личная позиция. Но это мы ещё обсуждаем с модераторами. Думаю, по этому поводу, когда всё станет ясно, напишем отдельный поясняющий пост на мете.

Answer (score -5):

> Может быть таким образом мы сможем показать абсурдность всей этой
>   идеи?

Есть реальные люди, которым очень не комфортно. И, чтобы сделать более благоприятные условия общения и для них тоже, вводятся эти поправки. Вы считаете это абсурдным?

> Ведь мы всё-таки на сайте для программистов, где ни пол, ни раса, ни национальность не играют никакой роли.

Им не место в самих вопросах/ответах. Но при общении в тех же комментариях немного другой формат.

А теперь по пунктам:

1. Я не понимаю, как вообще родилась мысль "просить использовать ru местоимения на en сайте". Сайт на английском, всё общение на английском. Что тут ещё добавить...
2. Касательно вот таких предложений

   > мы можем потребовать использования кириллических местоимений

   Не "требовать", а "попросить". Это, во-первых. Во-вторых, просить такое с криками "Ура, бьём противника его же оружием" - это неуважение к другим участникам.
3. Тут уже шутили про "называйте меня вертолётиком". Такие шутейки весьма не уместны.
4. Всякие призывы и т.п. кому-то назло прошу прекратить. От этого лучше никому не будет.
5. Относитесь ко всему этому как к просьбе. Это чем-то похоже на то, когда вас просят обращаться на "вы".
6. Отдельно, с точки зрения модератора, хочу попросить не проверять систему на прочность и не троллить. Лучше от этого никому не будет.

Comment: Так-то мне тоже(как и многим) много чего не комфортно, но я не кричу об этом направо и налево, так как я понимаю, что есть большинство, которому это удобно. Если под каждого конкретного индивида все подстраивать, то стабильная система превратится в хаос. Вспомните, как термин master/slave спешно меняли во всем коде чихая на совместимость с имеющимся кодом на всяких лидеров и фоловеров. Это не правильно.

Comment: Ах, как к просьбе? То есть можно и игнорировать, это же _просто просьба_? Это вы как модератор заявляете, можно верить? А Монику-то за что прогнали?

Comment: @iluxa1810 неправильно - это перетягивать одеяло на себя, приговаривая, что "не нужно подстраиваться под меньшинство". Если это кому-то сделает жизнь чуточку лучше, а вам ничем это не грозит, то в чём проблема?

Comment: @VladD я сказал, что я отношусь к этому как к просьбе. Про Монику я не в курсе, они это публично не обсуждают (в мод. чате тоже). Моника с сотрудникам напрямую общается, как я понял.

Comment: На самом деле притянутую логику в этом можно найти. Например мой гендер - это суровый русский мужик, у меня медведь в гараже, пишу комментарий в ушанке, без предварительно выпитой чарки самогона на сайт не захожу. Посему желаю обращения не "he", а "on" :)

Comment: SJW-это организация троллей. Если не кормить троллей, то про них забуду. Я уже где-то приводил примеры: God Of War главного белого героя озвучивал темнокожий актер и все молчали. Devil May Cry 5 темнокожего второстепенного героя(который минут 5 экранного времени имеет) озвучивая белый актер и все воняют. Mortal Komat- Соню Блейд озвучивает девушка, которая учавствует в реальных боях. Игру освестали за то, что эта девушка в одном из поединков отказалась драться с трансом, боясь, что ее изувечат.

Comment: В английском использовали "must": _"you must respect that and use them"_ - "ты обязан". Это не просьба, а именно требование. Пользователь _требует_ использовать местоимение, а другой _обязан_ подчиниться.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ага, а вот некоторые люди убивают других людей. Поэтому все люди убийцы, если продолжать вашу логику. Зачем вы действия троллей проецируете на всю группу?

Comment: @Suvitruf это сделает чуточку жизнь лучше только им, но сделает дискомфорт большинству. Если бы это был личный выбор каждого, то не вопрос, а тут именно принуждение.

Comment: @Qwertiy я сказал, как я это воспринимаю и написал, что лучше относиться к этому как к просьбе. Я не говорил, что в оригинале просьба.

Comment: @iluxa1810 какой дискомфорт вы от этого испытываете?

Comment: @Suvitruf, если это просьба, то надо чтобы кто-то поменял соответствующим образом правила. Они _намеренно_ сформулировали так, что это не просьба.

Comment: @Suvitruf, как я понимаю, я смогу словить пред, если я буду общаться без какой-либо враждебности, а потом окажется, что упустил какое-то особенно местоимение.

Comment: SJW пытаются подстроить мир под себя и это не правильно. Вот недавно были новости, что кого-то оскорбляет такой танец, как Танго. Ну не нравится? Не смотри. Зачем менять то, что является обыденностью для большинства под меньшинство?

Comment: @iluxa1810 можно словить предупреждение, если вас попросили обращаться конкретным местоимением, но вы проигнорировали. Если вы делали это по не знанию, то никто никого наказывать не будет.

Comment: @iluxa1810 "Ну не нравится? Не смотри", т.е. этим людям вы предлагает просто уйти с сайта? Или предлагаете им тихо молчать и страдать дальше?

Comment: @Suvitruf я привел в пример абсурдность их требований приведя в пример Танго. Просто, дойдет до того, что гонясь за меньшинством, с сайта уйдет % большинства. Сегодня они диктуют свои местоимения, а завтра им не нравится O==0 в коде, так как это вызывает некоторые ассоциации и будь добр цензурируй код, что бы кого-то не оскорбить.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы сейчас приводите примеры с других областей и аппроксимируете это на SO. Никто не хочет подобного тут. Вас смущает именно форма? Если бы там было это в форме просьбы, то вопросов бы у вас не было?

Comment: @Suvitruf Если бы был рекомендательный характер, но не обязательный, то пофигу.

Comment: @Suvitruf `какой дискомфорт вы от этого испытываете?` - дискомфорт от навязывания правил,  польза которых к тому же сомнительная.

Comment: @AntonSorokin дайте время этой инициативе, посмотрим к чему это приведёт. Зачем изначально настраиваться на негатив?

Comment: @Suvitruf хм, откуда же появился негатив? Может из-за действий администрации сайта, которые предшествовали публикации КоКа?

Comment: @Suvitruf Да скорее всего некоторый % просто уйдет с платформы и все. Кто вообще воспользуется шумихой и сделает свой SO с блекджеком и все остальным, где не будет ненужных правил.

Comment: @iluxa1810 не сделают

Comment: @Qwertiy "you must respect that and use them" откуда это? Не вижу в новом CoC такого.

Comment: @Suvitruf, это Q10 из [вопроса с FAQ](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/334900/309650).

Comment: @Qwertiy ага, вижу. Интересный момент. В CoC этого долженствования нет. Т.е, большинство участников про это и не узнает. Хм.

Comment: @iluxa1810 насчет "некомфортно" - вы просто воспринимаете это как "какие-то сторонние SJW требуют непонятно чего, а на самом деле ничего нет, это все фантазии". На практике же даже среди мод состава SO есть люди, которых эти самые ze / they напрямую зацепили.

Comment: @iluxa1810 просто вы, как he, не понимаете, насколько это *некомфортно*, когда тебя принудительно относят к другому полу. Я как-то раз зарегистрировался на сайте данона, и знаете, даже нотификации, в которых к вам обращаются как к "участнице", очень хорошо позволяют почувствовать это "некомфортно" :)

Comment: @PashaPash я думаю, что если кто нибудь на SO попросил других называть себя `she/he и т.п`, ему бы никто не отказал. Моя сущность бунтует именно из-за принудительного спуска странных(не в плане именования полом, которым попросили именовать, а в плане исполнения и конкретно отдельного пункта для этого) правил. 

Думаю у многих так - если что-то принуждают делать, то это вообще не хочется делать.

Comment: @PashaPash: а судьи кто?

Comment: @AntonSorokin это просто последствия формализации правил. CoC - это детально разжёванные базовые правила, с которыми вроде как все более-менее согласны (по крайней точно согласно большинство в en сегменте). Точно так же в правилах "сверху спущено" не оскорблять, например - вы же из-за этого не начинаете бунтовать и материть всех подряд :) Воспринимайте это как правило "не оскорбляйте, не материтесь, и если участница сказала, что она - на самом деле он (или не он и не она) - то не стоит дальше называть участника "она", несмотря на пони на аватаре"

Comment: Есть гораздо больше людей, которые испытывают дискомфорт от чего угодно, кроме местоимений. Я лично знаю людей, которых раздражает слово "человек" в их адрес. Меня лично оскорбляет классификация парафилий в современной медицине. Да, несмотря на очень малое число трансгендров, они объединились с гомосексуалами, бисексуалами и прочими, и поэтому их голос услышан, но вы явно преувеличиваете как число людей, которых оскорбляют местоимения, так и силу дискомфорта (подробную статистику можете посмотреть в моём ответе).

Comment: @VladD те же судьи, что и при тревогах за оскорбление.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Я может и не знаю, как там на Meta.SE, а у нас трактовка оскорблений по моей памяти подчёркнуто неадекватная.

Comment: @VladD мне прилетает тревога "оскорбление". Мне как-то нужно определить, действительно ли оно так. Совсем явные троллинг тревоги легко вычислить. Но в остальном сложно порой. Если бы вы читали посты на MSE (особенно недавние), то заметили бы, сколько из них было удалено. Я бы сказал, что у нас **возможно** есть проблемы с тревогами за клевету, т.к. это довольно тяжело формализуемая штука.

Comment: @Suvitruf: А за что банили тогда ещё Athari на год, напомните? У нас с адекватностью оценок проблема размером с Юпитер.

Comment: @VladD год, насколько я помню, т.к. это был рецидив. Поправьте, если я не прав.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Вы можете поинтересоваться у остальных модераторов, что было объявленной причиной. Есть мнение, что эта формальная причина далека от реальной.

Comment: @VladD по причину сейчас не скажу. Я именно про срок бана сейчас.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Срок бана, как известно, определяется лично модератором. Вам ли этого не знать.

Comment: @VladD конечный срок да. Но есть все эти рекомендации и т.п. Какой смысл сейчас Атари обсуждать? Я не спорю, что год - это **возможно** перебор.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Я лишь приводил пример того, что с модерацией у нас, *возможно*, есть тяжёлые проблемы.

Comment: @VladD перегибы есть на всех сайтах, это я вам как свидетель говорю. И неоднозначность мнений среди модераторов тоже.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Я и не спорю с этим тезисом. Я лишь говорю о том, что наши перегибы процентуально и качественно отличаются от их перегибов. Вы сами, думаю, можете сказать, в какую сторону. А проблемы есть везде, это знают все.