# Кто такая Моника, и почему сообщество так часто упоминает это имя?

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, нормы-поведения, кризис-2019

Часто встречаю имя "Моника" и кучу обсуждений внутри сообщества, где оно фигурирует. Нередко эти обсуждения довольно яростны. Что произошло и от чего такая реакция ?

Comment: Имху полный дубликат https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9549/

Comment: @AK не думаю. В том плане, что в том вопросе эта ситуация лишь кратко освещена. Плюс нету описания последних событий.

Comment: Leks, dопрос хороший, но задан очень плохо

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica в аэропорту сейчас, сложно редактировать с мобилы. Попытался поправить, чтоб внести ясность в вопрос. Что думаете?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica а вы молодец. У меня после всех этих событий желание вкладываться в SE поубавилось.

Comment: Про «признаки агрессии» в посте ОПа не было.

Comment: @VladD можете поправить, если хотите. Я агрессию наблюдаю на MSE со всех сторон.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica я никогда ничего не делал **для компании SE**, мне многие их действия не нравятся. Я всё делаю **для участников**. По крайней мере, я себя так убеждаю, иначе мотивации бы совсем не было =/

Comment: @Suvitruf: То, что наблюдается на MSE — это не агрессия (ну разве что по меркам некоторых очень чувствительных к критике представителей администрации), это критика. Была бы это реальная агрессия, за неё бы забанили.

Comment: @VladD о, вы просто не видите всех удалённых сообщений. Там очень много реально треша, вплоть до угроз и мата =/

Comment: @VladD впрочем, обоснованной критики тоже хватает. Там насколько я знаю, в ближайшее время будет пост от SE по поводу фидбека. Может что-то  изменится в лучшую сторону. Хотя я скептичен в этом вопросе.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Ну поскольку ОП вряд ли видит удалённые сообщения, думаю, он не имел их в виду.

Comment: @VladD возможно вы правы. Поправил.

Comment: @Kromster says support Monica Когда я в последнее время устраивал хороший dопрос ?

Comment: @Leks товариш, пройдёмте в отделение (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Что дает репа и плюсы? Почему все так хотят стать модераторами? Что это им даст?

Comment: @Человек, задайте отдельный вопрос здесь на Мете (кнопка Задать вопрос справа сверху).

Comment: @Человек а вообще можете почитать справку: [Что такое репутация?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), [Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: А модераторам платят деньги? Почему они так держатся за свои места?

Comment: Нет. Это призвание у них такое

Comment: Ну я хз, зачем это, тогда им нужно))

Еще устраивают интриги похлеще Игры престолов)))

Comment: Сообщение было опубликовано в качестве ответа, но оно не содержит ответа на вопрос. Сообщение может быть правкой, комментарием, другим вопросом, но, возможно, его стоит просто удалить.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Как уже @AK отметил, частично это затрагивалось в другом вопросе: [Уход модераторов сети Stack Exchange](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9549/15479).

Там, на самом деле, долгая история. И она не то, чтобы очень сильно связанна с какими-то конкретными событиями. Очень многим не нравится (особенно в последние годы), как SE, как компания, разруливает публичные, хм, конфликты. Особенно это было заметно по сообщениям/действиям в Твиттере. Вроде [вот этой ситуации](https://twitter.com/birdsarah/status/1156356051190636544).

Обострилось всё недавно, когда решили поменять CoC. Там был щепетильный вопрос по поводу местоимений. Скажем, если трансгендер, который биологически является парнем, считает себя женщиной и просит обращаться к нему на she/her вместо he/him, то вы должны выполнить эту просьбу. Если после его просьбы продолжить обращаться к участнику, используя "неправильное местоимение", то это является нарушением правил.

У нас это частично обсуждали: [Местоимения. Пока не про нас, но есть вопросы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9603/15479).

Можете посмотреть [профиль самой Моники](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio). И почитать обсуждения по теме:

- [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/260198)
- [Stack Overflow Inc., sinat chinam, and the goat for Azazel](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5193).
- [Блог Моники](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/).
- [Let's take a look at the interaction between staff and the "power users" of the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331513/260198).

Если кратко:

- Было некое взаимонедопонимание в чате для модераторов между Моникой и участником LGBT сообщества. Намерений и попыток оскорбить, замечу, там не было.
- Потом встал конфликт между Моникой и некоторыми сотрудниками SE на этой почве.
- С неё сняли лычки модератора в обход правил и процедуры по причине "нарушений CoC". При этом новый CoC и пункты, по которым её можно было обвинить в чём-то, ещё не были опубликованы.
- После чего SE публично [в интервью журналу сказали, что Моника нарушила правила](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/).
- Все просьбы и сообщения Моники были проигнорированы компанией.
- Компания отказывается публично что-то комментировать по юридическим причинам.
- [Многие модераторы добровольно ушли с постов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/260198) в поддержку Моники. На некоторых сайтах сети не осталось активных модераторов вовсе.
- [Моника сейчас собирает деньги на юриста](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users).
- [Компания насильно вырезает из сообщений и профилей участников ссылки на компанию по сбору денег](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338271/260198). [Эффект Стрейзанд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4) в действии.
- Многие участники в поддержку Моники меняют ники и аватарки. Кто-то информацию в профиле ещё меняет.
- Если верить [недавнему обновлению](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/260198) по всей этой ситуации ([перевод на нашей Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9920/15479)), то Моника и SE пришли к какому-то соглашению. Комментировать ситуацию обе стороны не могут по юридическим причинам. Компания на GoFundMe прекращена, деньги пойдут на благотворительность. При этом Монику в должности не восстановили.
- После увольнения ключевых сотрудников (Shog9 and Robert) компанией, [Моника больше не верит, что возможны изменения к лучшему, и решила окончательно покинуть SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342950/260198).

Можно также послушать [подкаст про это дело с самой Моникой](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs).

Очень сложно мне всё это собрать в кучу. Там очень много обсуждений было по теме. Надеюсь, я хоть немного прояснил ситуацию. В моём сообщении нет какой-то личной оценки ситуации, я лишь постарался собрать факты в кучу.

Comment: *"считает себя женщиной и просит обращаться к нему на she/her вместо he/him"* Там еще интереснее. Он может считать себя ни мужчиной, ни женщиной, и попросить использовать кастомное местоимение, а-ля [xe/xer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third-person_pronoun#Summary) - их правила тоже [требуют использовать](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336368/353058).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat это уже нюансы. Суть в том, что это теперь не как просьба должно рассматриваться, а как требование. И модераторам на этот счёт весьма чёткие установки даны =/

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica как я понял на мете не начисляются балы за вопросы и ответы ?

Comment: @Leks репутация не начисляется, да. Но баджики выдают (:

Comment: @Leks [знаки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Comment: @Leks [Нормы поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Отличный ответ. Стало понятнее. У меня одного не хватает времени на обсуждения такого рода?)

Comment: @doox911 до сих пор пытаюсь понять, как занятые программисты и инженеры помимо личных вопросов и обсуждений кода успевают что либо писать\читать на мете (O_o)

Comment: @finally людям свойственно собираться вместе. А в данном случае людей объединяет весьма конкретное увлечение. Занятно это, на самом деле, т.к. в противовес этим желаниям участников, компания пытается сделать из сообщества лишь QA сайт (:

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica все чаще замечаю, что люди, заходящие на SO не просят помощи, не обсуждают проблему, а будто заставляют помогать им, идет эдакая борьба за репу, ибо если взять дефолтные метки, вроде python, то там вопросы по типу "помогите новичку", или "не могу разобраться", где решение лежит на поверхности и не требует особых усилий дается сразу, а вот вопросы более сложного и интересного характера, требующие не просто знания синтаксиса, либо игнорируются, либо довольствуются парочкой ответов в комментариях, грустно(

Comment: @finally за сложные вопросы мало репы получаешь. Ну да, другие такие же профи поставят плюсик. Ну будет их 5, а ты на ответ несколько часов мог убить. Вот, думаю, и не пытаются даже поэтому. Отдачи почти за старания нет.

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica как мне кажется - это и есть основная проблема, а не оскорбления всяких нетрадиционных..

Comment: FWIW: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340906/update-an-agreement-with-monica-cellio

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin два дня назад добавил это в свой ответ)

Comment: Ой, и правда; пардон. Там просто в ответе столько ссылок, что у меня лимит на вкладки в браузере вышел :)

Comment: Насчет "вот этой ситуации". Двое отклонивших то простые пользователи, разве не так? При чем тут компания, я не понял

Comment: Хмм, если вы про комментарии, то оные от SO почищены. Ответы же на них не дают поводов для подозрений в том, что они написали что-то плохое. Ладно, даже если это были модераторы, то это просто их мнение. Я думаю, что они вольны принять или отклонить по своему усмотрению.