# Кто предложил аватар в поддержку Моники?

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, кризис-2019

Кто предложил эту эмблему движения восстановителей Моники?

[image]

**P.S** это [вопрос](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340749/260198), который я задал на MSE, он набрал там +21 рейтинг и был удалён их модератором.

Comment: *Шутка за 300*Хм... А почему обе руки белые? Меня, как афроамериканца в душе это оскорбляет!*Шутка за 300*

Comment: Ссылочку бы на тот пост.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Думаю, нужно сделать свой значок - REINSTATE OUR HAT

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Вот ссылочка, только вопрос удаленный , или вы как модератор можете его созерцать ;) ?
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340749/who-created-the-monica-reinstatement-symbol

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica у меня там 10к+ репутации. Могу видеть удалённые посты.

Comment: А вот как... А восстановить случайно нельзя? ;)

Comment: А что случилось-то?

Comment: @AlexDevTime https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9786/15479

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, если верить [словам Mari-Lou A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336024/how-can-we-put-pressure-on-stack-exchange-inc-without-damaging-the-community/336283#comment1111923_336283), то автором был [J.R.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/180981/j-r-means-just-reinstate)

[ColleenV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/273494/colleenv-parted-ways) тоже [писал](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340749/who-created-the-monica-reinstatement-symbol#comment1139005_340749), что картинку от J.R. получил.

Касательно же удаления...не думаю, что есть шанс восстановления вопроса. Его Journeyman Geek удалял. У него на счёт таких постов чёткая позиция.