# Cоглашение с Моникой Челлио

Tags: обсуждение, stackexchange, кризис-2019

Сегодня на MSE произошло важное событие: ["Cоглашение с Моникой Челлио](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340906/550438)"

---

Вот перевод:

> Stack Overflow и Моника Челлио пришли к соглашению. Мы верим, что г-жа Челлио не имела злого умысла. Мы считаем, что она не поняла всех нюансов, а также дух и смысл нашего Code of Conduct (кодекса поведения), и неправильно поняла, к чему он обязывает и что запрещает.
>
> Мы признаём, что наши ответы на её просьбы о разъяснениях были неудовлетворительными. Формулировки нашего Code of Conduct, касающиеся того, что именно ожидается от пользователей, были недостаточно точны. Мы всегда ценили вклад г-жи Челлио в сообщество и уважали её ум, честность и её профессиональные навыки писателя.
>
> Хотя в нашем первоначальном заявлении мы не говорили конкретно о ней, мы сожалеем, что упомянули её имя, когда отвечали на вопросы репортера. Мы сожалеем о любом уроне, нанесённом репутации г-жи Cellio, и о любом другом ущербе, который она могла понести.
>
> С тех пор мы обновили некоторые наши политики и процессы, чтобы гарантировать, что впредь мы будем более осторожны в наших публичных заявлениях, и чтобы у нас была более чёткая процедура снятия модераторов с должности, и возвращения их в должность.
>
> Мы уважаем г-жу Челлио и считаем, что она хороший человек, который может многое предложить сообществу. Мы искренне надеемся, что она останется активным членом нашего сообщества. Признавая ошибки, которые привели нас сюда, мы предложили г-же Челлио подать заявку на возможное восстановление полномочий модератора на всех шести сайтах, посредством прохождения нашей новой процедуры восстановления модератора в должности. Г-жа Челлио выразила озабоченность по поводу нового процесса, и не стала подавать заявку.

Comment: Моника [закрыла сбор средств](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users), и, видимо, больше не будет судиться. Оставшиеся деньги пойдут на благотворительность (сколько именно осталось - посчитает и напишет позднее). Похоже, на этом драма закончится.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat В смысле она вернется на пост модераторов или нет?

Comment: Вернется только если согласится пройти новую [процедуру восстановления в должности](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336177/feedback-post-moderator-review-and-reinstatement-processes). Она отказалась, потому что процедура хреновая - ничто не мешает SO сказать "ну, мы посовещались согласно этой процедуре, и решили, что ромб не вернем".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну это будет просто подлость. Если возвращать — то возвращать.

Comment: Угу. По ссылке есть пост Моники с критикой этой самой процедуры.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Окей, спасибо за правку и за разъяснение ;)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Через тревогу можно попросить? И еще я где-то читал что за это снимают 500 репы — не хотелось бы потерять.

Comment: Тег `важное` поставили, репутация на месте. Это миф.

Comment: все code of conduct должны быть отправлены в /dev/null

Comment: @etki вместе с их авторами? (¬‿¬ )

Comment: *"Мы **всегда** ценили вклад г-жи Челлио в сообщество и уважали её ум, честность и её профессиональные навыки писателя."* - ловко они в полёте переобулись-то...

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica кое-кого, кто в очередной раз лжёт всему сообществу SE, и правда пора отправить в /dev/null.

Comment: @NickVolynkin может статься, что почти никого не останется тогда в команде   ┐(︶▽︶)┌

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica ну так и поделом им.

Comment: *"Мы сожалеем о любом уроне, **нанесенном** репутации г-жи Cellio"* - в оригинале намеренно не указано об источнике урона. *"**Г-жа** Челлио выразила несогласие"*. если сокращать везде, то и тут тоже.

Comment: SO извинились публично О_о Мы на Земле?

Comment: Оценки вопроса-объявления и ответа Моники на него как бы намекают, что кому-то штаны стирать уже нужно. Однако уже хоть что-то.

Comment: @L.F.C., всё в порядке... собственно __извинений__ в сабже нет...

Comment: Рамзана на них нет. Сейчас бы быстро извинились

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Перевод топового ответа от Script47 ([источник](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340913/403480)):

---

Может быть, жесткая критика, но я верю, что честная и справедливая.

Ваш пост звучит так, как будто ваши адвокаты подготовили его для вас.
В тексте  отсутствует человечность, есть только рафинированный канцелярский язык.

> Stack Overflow и Моника Челлио пришли к соглашению. **Мы верим, что
>   г-жа Челлио не имела злого умысла. Мы считаем, что она не поняла всех
>   нюансов, а также дух и смысл нашего Code of Conduct (кодекса
>   поведения), и неправильно поняла, к чему он обязывает и что
>   запрещает.**

Мы уже установили это. Что не было установлено, так это то, почему ее просьбы о разъяснениях были проигнорированы с такой силой.

> Мы признаём, что наши ответы на её просьбы о разъяснениях были
>   неудовлетворительными. Формулировки нашего Code of Conduct, касающиеся
>   того, что именно ожидается от пользователей, были недостаточно точны.
>   **Мы всегда ценили вклад г-жи Челлио в сообщество и уважали её ум, честность и её профессиональные навыки писателя.**

Неужели? Тогда бы вы поступили с ней любезно, ответив раньше, и не стали бы ждать, пока потребуются адвокаты. Вы бы относились к ней немного с достоинством и порядочностью, не разговаривая с прессой.

> Хотя в нашем первоначальном заявлении мы не говорили конкретно о ней,
>   мы сожалеем, что упомянули её имя, когда отвечали на вопросы
>   репортера. **Мы сожалеем о любом уроне, нанесённом репутации г-жи
>   Cellio, и о любом другом ущербе, который она могла понести.**

Сказал адвокат...

> С тех пор мы обновили некоторые наши политики и процессы, чтобы
>   гарантировать, что впредь мы будем более осторожны в наших публичных
>   заявлениях, и чтобы у нас была более чёткая процедура снятия
>   модераторов с должности, и возвращения их в должность.

Вы изменили политику в результате непрекращающихся проблем. Не потому, что вы поняли ошибку.

Давайте проясним, модераторы постоянно говорят пользователям, что они не обсуждают отстранение пользователей, так почему же сотрудник посчитал нужным сделать это с прессой?

Грубая халатность или простой злой умысел?

> Мы уважаем г-жу Челлио и считаем, что она хороший человек, который
>   может многое предложить сообществу. Мы искренне надеемся, что она
>   останется активным членом нашего сообщества. Признавая ошибки, которые
>   привели нас сюда, мы предложили г-же Челлио подать заявку на возможное
>   восстановление полномочий модератора на всех шести сайтах, посредством
>   прохождения нашей новой процедуры восстановления модератора в
>   должности. Г-жа Челлио выразила озабоченность по поводу нового
>   процесса, и не стала подавать заявку.

Опять же сказал адвокат, и из-за этого вы кажетесь невероятно неосведомленными.

Как же *ХОРОШО* с вашей стороны '*пригласить*' ее подать заявление на восстановление *ХОТЯ* вы признали, что это были **ВАШИ** ошибки.

Весь этот пост показывает, что вы возмещаете ущерб не потому, что вы действительно чувствуете, что была совершена ошибка, а потому, что это то, что вам сказали делать ***так*** адвокаты, если вы хотите чтобы все уладилось. Если вы собираетесь извиниться, делайте это, не рассказывая о недостатках другого человека.

У Моники, должно быть, было очень хорошее дело, чтобы вы даже опубликовали этот пост.

---

В любом случае, я рад, что Моника получила разрешение, которое она может подписать.

Comment: Качество перевода весьма хромает ..

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica Я старался ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "Lawyer speak" это скорее "адвокатский язык", а не "сказал адвокат"

Comment: "The humanity has been sucked out of it, canned lawyer speak is what remains." - смысл в том, что в тексте отсутствует человечность, а остался только рафинированный ("консервированный") канцелярский язык.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama Для "lawyer speak" думаю это означает одно и тоже. За второе спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

[Ответ Моники](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/340914/159796):

> I can't comment further for legal reasons.

> Я больше не могу комментировать, по юридическим причинам.

Comment: Откатил добавленные ссылки на комменты от Сары, т.к. обе ссылки на один и тот же коммент, и не понятно каким боком это относится к ответу Моники.