# Добровольная отставка модератора Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Люди спрашивают, с чем связаны [новые выборы модераторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1). Планировал о своём решении объявить уже после окончания выборов. Но да ладно.

Решил уйти с поста. В сущности, новые выборы с этим и связаны. Не буду особо расписывать причины ухода, т.к. мало кому это интересно, да и нет смысла одно и то же обсуждать по 100 раз. Тезисно лишь напишу основные причины:

1. Я изначально выдвигался на позицию с расчётом в год-два (в зависимости от того, что предпримет компания), т.к. считаю, что такие должности должны сменяться.
2. На решение сильно повлияла [ситуация с Моникой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9787/15479) и прочие решения компании.
3. Уход [Шога](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/260198) и [Джона](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342424/260198) ещё больше подтолкнули к этому решению.

Было приятно помогать нашему сообществу. С разрешения остальных модераторов выкладываю статистику по работе за последний год.

[image: статистика модерации]

После окончания выборов какое-то время буду помогать новичкам освоиться, а потом уйду. Всем спасибо.

И помните, что для модерации и помощи сообществу не нужно быть модератором. Рядовые участники имеющимися средствами могут и сами решать многие вопросы.

Comment: Вы же *уйдёте* с поста модератора, а не с SO вообще? ಥ_ಥ Предпоследний абзац испугал.

Comment: Жаль. Ромб Вам очень идёт.

Comment: Жаль... ( Может передумаете ???

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за ту огромную работу, что Вы сделали для сообщества! За этот год у нас было немало спорных ситуаций, но все они, благодаря Вам и остальной команде модераторов, успешно разрешались. Находить компромисс между незнакомыми людьми и поддерживать порядок в многотысячном комьюнити — это тяжёлая работа, заслуживающая уважения.

Comment: Спасибо за активную работу, сообщество помнит :)

Comment: Надеюсь, отсутствие ромба пойдёт лишь на пользу, позволив отдохнуть, и Вы с новыми силами продолжите участвовать в развитии нашего сообщества :)

Comment: Судя по красным звёздочкам, следующий на самоудаление - Qwertiy. А статистику хорошо бы по годам/месяцам, а не за всё время. Ну или среднее число с момента инаугурации.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ звёздочка означает, что модератор не принял новое соглашение модератора. По годам стату не посмотреть. Там на выбор день/неделя/месяц/квартал/всё время.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik на самом деле ещё и за год можно, просто надо вручную период в запрос вбить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin?filter=year

Comment: Жаль конечно, что уходите, но я благодарен и за то, что было сделано. Спасибо за проделанную работу.

Comment: F, что тут скажешь.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь сообществу!

Comment: Спасибо, что пытались. Спасибо, что не цепляетесь за власть. Спасибо, что при вас не было больших драм.

Comment: @Nofate F ????? (15, false, Suvitru**F**)?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor "press F to pay respect"

Comment: Мяу.‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏‎‏

Comment: Очень жаль что вы уходите. Но прекрасно понимаю ваши причины. В любом случае - удачи вам!

Answer (score 16):

Большое спасибо за ваш вклад в развитие сообщества и русскоязычной базы знаний!

Мне повезло встретиться с вами лично до вашего прихода в коллектив модераторов и поговорить совсем не давно, в рамках видео чата сообщества. На мой взгляд, вы стали добрее и относитесь с большим пониманием к коллегам. Если посмотреть на вашу активность на сайте и в чате за последний год, видно что вы не раз выступали тем, кто пытался разрешить возникающие конфликты конструктивно. Это очень здорово =)

Большое спасибо и удачи в следующем приключении!