# А не устроить ли нам выборы?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, выборы

Собственно, сабж. Уже почти 5 лет сайт ruSO живёт [без выделенного управляющего](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217) и жил бы, наверное, ещё очень долго, если бы не наступили сложные времена. Похоже, что [скоро](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12417/176217) (или как это обычно здесь происходит, в течение 6-8 недель) нам объявят о появлении нового КМ, готового содействовать в решении насущных проблем сообщества.

Но пока этого формально не произошло, и мы находимся на самообеспечении, не задумать ли нам провести выборы модераторов? Старых модераторов это действие, конечно, не снимет. Но как минимум разбавит (должно бы) застойную ситуацию во взаимодействии с сообществом.

С [предыдущих выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/4) прошло уже два с половиной года и как неожиданно (никаких анонсов на Мете ведь не было) для меня выяснилось после посещение этой страницы - один из выбранных тогда модераторов уже лишён ромба! Это ли не повод ускориться в проведении новых выборов?!

Что скажет сообщество по этому поводу? Что скажешь ТЫ?

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь высказывать свои мысли в секции ответов, а не комментариев. Репутация не пострадает, на Мете она не такая как на основном сайте.

Comment: Пойдете строить заговоры к нам в команду? )

Comment: @Nofate я пока не умею выборы под себя организовывать

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, тогда вы нам не подходите (¬‿¬)

Comment: А поможет? Уверены, что новая средняя температура по больнице будет лучше?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat коней на переправе не меняют?

Comment: Я так и не понял чем модеры занимаются, но, видимо, на то они и модеры, чтобы их работа не была видна) В том плане, что ВНЕШНЕ оно и не заметно, модерируется ли сообщество модерами или просто ответственными гражданами с расширенными полномочиями. Да, иногда всплывают скандалы/интриги/расследования, но в целом наше "болото" (без обид) вроде как нормально существует. Если выборы ради выборов, то почему бы и нет. Если на ruSO есть проблемы, о которых нам не говорят, но которые можно решить, то тоже ЗА выборы)

Comment: Если модераторский состав справляется и сам не поднимает этот вопрос, то не вижу в этом смысла. Из кого выбирать? Зачем? Где гарантия, что не станет хуже? Выборы ради выборов? Какая разница сколько времени прошло с момента выборов? Модератор как вино - со временем становится лучше. Самое главное чтоб не скис. P.S.: а чем конкретно сможет помочь сообществу КМ? У него какие-то особенные полномочия?

Comment: @XelaNimed, KM - сотрудник компании, поэтому да, у него особенные полномочия и действия которые не могут сделать модераторы

Comment: @XelaNimed странные вопросы задаёте, уважаемый. С [этой темой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12267/176217) знакомы? Депутаты решили, что ГД справляется, выборы не нужны, зачем новых ртов набирать из народа. Да?

Comment: А смысл? Я понимаю еще, полные перевыборы - для старых переизбрание - как вотум доверия, а так к чему заводиться? Обнулить сроки :), и достаточно...

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ну... Какие у меня вопросы возникают, те и задаю. С темой знаком, но при таком подходе новый мод.состав опять будет переизбираться при первом косяке/возмущении что ли?! Может быть у самих модераторов нужно спросить, а не устал ли кто-то из них? Не думаю, что эта ответственность как манна небесная... Тот-же Grundy может уже устал и не хочет более тащить эту лямку, но не знает как спрыгнуть... Не знаю... По-моему мнению можно ситуацию разрулить "полюбовно" и жить дальше.

Comment: @XelaNimed а разве выборы - это не "полюбовно"? Кто полюбился, того и выбирают. Даже голосовать не обязательно, принудиловки никакой нет, бюджет не пострадает, модераторов стало меньше (без объяснения причин), так почему бы не донабрать, мирно, без трэшака? ПЕРЕВЫБОРЫ никто не предлагает, существующих модераторов выборы не снимают, выборы добавляют новых. А снять модераторов могут в любой момент, выборы для этого не нужны. Пример как раз в вопросе приведён.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ не могу с Вами не согласиться. Скорее всего не внимательно читал, либо понял что-то не так. А кто должен выборы организовывать и как/когда/исходя из каких критериев? На сколько я понимаю, нашего желания мало, или? Сколько сейчас, так сказать, вакантных мест? Что говорят/думают по этому поводу сами модераторы?

Comment: @XelaNimed [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99515/339911) сказано, что менеджмент сообщества решает при содействии с модераторами. В любом случае нажать кнопку "начать выборы" на сайте X без сотрудников SE нельзя. Но помочь им на это решиться мы можем, голосованием в данном вопросе в том числе. О чём думают модераторы только модераторы могут рассказать, но они как-то очень неохотно на Мете выступают.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ > модераторов стало меньше (без объяснения причин). 
Никаких заговоров тут нет. У компании есть политика автоматического удаления неактивных в течение полугода модераторов, которые при этом не находятся "в отпуске". Да и Бармалей в предвыборной речи писал "(через год точно уйду)".

Comment: @DaemonHK чем занимаются модераторы можно увидеть вкратце [в соседней теме](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12419/1984)

Comment: @Nofate что ж, получается модератор, который сдержал свой предвыборный лозунг. Хотя если был бы анонс на Мете, было бы лучше и меньше недоразумений/предположений. Как раньше делали [Suvitruf - Andrei Apanasik](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10773/176217) и [A K](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10777/176217).

Comment: А сколько нужно репутации, чтобы участвовать в голосовании?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ так-то если смотреть лозунги - все модераторы выполняют

Comment: @Зонтик для голосования 150, для выдвижения 300 (и 18+).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ а как они проверяют возраст?

Comment: @Danis возраст не проверяется формально, однако при "подсписании" модераторского соглашения - такой пункт есть и ты формально сам декларируешь, что тебе уже есть 18. [модераторское соглашение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) и [соответствующая статья](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357377/383809)

Comment: цитирую: "We will rely on our Moderators to self-report for this policy. When nominating you'll say you're above 18 and we'll trust you. If you're already a Moderator, let us know if you're under 18. Moderators who let us know or who are discovered to be under age will have their diamond removed until they reach the age of 18, at which point they can request reinstatement in an abbreviated process."

Comment: вот так вот....уйдешь в работу ненадолго - а тут такое творится!

Comment: выборы определенно нужны...модераторский состав заметно проредел.

Comment: Выборы нужны.... НО кто их будет проводить?

Comment: @Зонтик центризбирком SO, как обычно, кто ж ещё.

Comment: @Зонтик сообщество выразит консенсус (кажется, что уже выразило) - выборы состоятся. Community Manager организует. Так что все будет кока-кола.

Comment: @AntonMenshov вроде Community Manager ещё не назанчен на наш сайт... Или он уже есть?

Comment: @Зонтик он есть, просто он ещё не выложил про это пост

Comment: @αλεχολυτ "я пока не умею выборы под себя организовывать " - жаль, мне кажется, вы бы были хорошим модератором =).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ И кстати, если не ошибаюсь, я видел вас в [списке кандидатов на одних из предыдущих выборов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9115/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0-2019-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0/9170#9170).

Comment: Будешь участвовать? )

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik пока ещё не решил :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ своевременно.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Мы посовещались в модераторском бункере, и я отправил от лица нашего сообщества заявку на проведение выборов двух новых модераторов.

Как вы понимаете, время ответа /contact недетерминировано. Так что, как обычно, будем подождать )

---

UPD1. По просьбе @αλεχολυτ — текст:

> Hi, folks!
> ru.stackoverflow.com community agreed on the need of new moderator elections.
> Active moderators agreed that 2 new positions should be enough.
> So, I think we are ready to initiate an election process.
>
> Relevant links:
> [А не устроить ли нам выборы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12418/1984)
> https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63181348#63181348
>
> Best regards,
> RU.SO moderators

---

UPD2. Ответственный за это CM уже пришел в модераторский чат.

---

UPD3. Старт кампании назначен на **28 марта**.

Comment: А скольких модераторов выбирать будем? `@Anton Menshov` писал: "На мой взгляд, вопрос должен стоять скорее о том, на сколько модераторских позиций открывать выборы: на одну или на две"

Comment: @Зонтик так написано же "двух"

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Извините, не заметил. Всё, покупаю букварь и учусь читать))

Comment: Т.е. старые остаются? Непорядок)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский надо ж преемников подготовить сначала. А кто там старый, кстати?

Comment: Кстати, сейчас 28 марта...

Comment: @Зонтик я тоже жду - что будет)

Comment: @eccs0103 хотите в модераторы?)

Comment: @Зонтик всего лишь смотреть, как все это делается.)

Comment: @eccs0103 я тоже)

Comment: Как поучаствовать в выборах? (сейчас, когда перехожу на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election, написано, что `Сейчас выборы модераторов сообщества не проводятся.`).

Comment: @wchistow ждем старта. Выборы еще не начинались. В NY еще только 8 утра.

Comment: @Nofate а этот старт примерно когда? В NY не знаю, но у меня уже 0։29 ночи.

Comment: @Nofate увидел редакцию. Не надо ответить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 20):

**Выборы нужны**.

1. Свежая кровь модераторскому составу абсолютно необходима.
2. Учитывая, что модераторы иногда уходят, хорошо заранее "готовить смену", чтобы в любой момент в модераторской группе были и опытные, и активные, и только приступившие к осовоению модерирования и модераторских инструментов.
3. Одна модераторская позиция недавно освободилась и по формальным признакам.
4. Видно, что у некоторых участников есть желание попробовать себя в ипостаси модератора. Будет здорово, если сообщество их поддержит и у них это получится.

На мой взгляд, вопрос должен стоять скорее о том, **на сколько** модераторских **позиций открывать выборы: на одну или на две**.

Comment: Если 1 свободна уже и что бы растить новые кадры, мне кажется надо открывать на 3, что бы было кому подстраховать.

Comment: @SwaD возможно, однако я не уверен, что в этом случае выборы будут конкурентны. Выборы на три позиции - не уверен, что есть столько желающих и тех, кто действительно готов вкладывать свое время.

Comment: Можно же всегда посмотреть на количество желающих и их качество и по результатам отобрать лучших. Если не получится 3х, то сколько получится. Это так, как предложение с предположением.

Comment: @SwaD ну не, если выбирать - только заранее определенное количество

Comment: @yolosora А вы случайно не бюрократ? ))) Почему обязательно выполнять "план" любой ценой?

Comment: @SwaD механизм выборов на SE обычно предполагает фиксированное количество позиций, и изменять его по итогам выборов - это требует дополнительных усилий (со стороны Community Manager) и обоснований. Поэтому закладывать такой сценарий как основной - проблематично.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Вот о таких "особенностях" не знал

Comment: Для трех новых модераторов объективно нет занятий. В выборах одного модератора мало интриги (скорее всего будет очевидный фаворит).

Comment: @Nofate, там и для одного нового нет занятий ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Если кое-кого свергнуть, может и будет работа ;)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не, не будет :-D

Comment: @Grundy можно не грести тревоги круглосуточно и делиться с другими.

Comment: @Nofate надо просто дать ему время успокоиться :-D

Comment: @αλεχολυτ. ha-ha, no.

Comment: @Nofate По опыту, подскажите, сколько времени отнимает модерирование(ну скажем в день)?

Comment: @SwaD но это ведь не работа, на которую мы ходим по расписанию. Я допустим, захожу утром и вечером в будни. В выходные когда как. Какой-то период вообще не было на это времени и сил. Когда какая-то новая большая проблема (как с ChatGPT в декабре-январе) бывает часами сидишь вникаешь в ситуацию, ищешь по чатам и потёртым комментариям, что происходит. Но в спокойные периоды в любой момент времени в очереди обычно не больше десятка тревог, да и по тем уже Grundy прошёлся. Поинтересуйтесь у него, сколько времени в день он тут проводит )

Comment: С другой стороны, чем больше модераторов, тем более вероятно, что в каждый момент времени кто-то из них просматривает сайт и не даст повода для жалоб типа "моя тревога уже 12 часов висит, всех пора разогнать" .

Comment: @Зонтик [тревоги могут "протухать"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system), после чего модераторы не видят их в списке тревог. Для разных типов тревог — разные сроки хранения. Если какая-то тревога висела две недели и не была обработана, обычно это значит, что модераторы не пришли к решению, что с ней делать. (И +1 модератор тут вряд ли поможет).

Comment: @Зонтик если речь о "голосах за закрытие", то это не к модераторам.

Comment: @Зонтик, имелся ввиду еще один новый модератор

Comment: Мне местечко оставьте (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что выборы нужны.

Как минимум один модератор недавно ушёл с поста. То есть модераторов стало меньше. В комментариях `@Grundy` говорил, что:

> там и для одного нового [модератора] нет занятий

Но новый модератор нужен. Чем больше модераторов, тем больше вероятность,
что на сайте всё время будет онлайн хотя бы один, то есть сайт будет +/- всегда "под наблюдением".

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/984/383809