# 2022: год в модерации

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, статистика

Прощаясь со старым годом и встречая новый, у нас есть [традиция делиться статистикой модерации за предыдущий год](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

Как известно многим, сеть сайтов Stack Exchange модерируются несколько иначе, чем другие сайты в Интернете:

> Мы разработали сетевой движок Stack Exchange так, чтобы он был в основном саморегулирующимся, поскольку мы компенсируем общую стоимость модерации системы за счет тысяч крошечных кусочков усилий, вносимых обычными повседневными пользователями.
> -- [Теория модерации](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Это не отменяет необходимость иметь [модераторов](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) в целом, но это означает, что основная часть модерации выполняется обычными людьми. Каждая частица времени и усилий, которые вы вкладываете в сайт, дает вам доступ к большему количеству привилегий, которые вы можете использовать, чтобы помочь в этом начинании, и все они производят кумулятивный эффект, который имеет большое значение.

Итак, пока мы прощаемся с 2022 годом (и куда делся январь, верно?) и ныряем с головой в 2023 год, давайте оглянемся назад на то, чего мы достигли как сообщество... взглянув на [*захватывающую* статистику](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif). Ниже приводится разбивка действий по модерации, выполненных на Stack Overflow на русском языке за последние 12 месяцев:

| Действие | Модераторы | Сообщество¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Все комментарии к публикации перенесенные в чат | 250 | 0 |
| Обработаны флаги ответов | 3,574 | 4,272 |
| Ответы отмечены флажками | 63 | 7,787 |
| Награды отменены | 1 | 0 |
| Обработаны флаги комментариев | 1,268 | 651 |
| Комментарии удалены⁷ | 7,551 | 15,316 |
| Комментарии отмечены флажками | 94 | 1,831 |
| Комментарии восстановлены | 80 | 0 |
| Расширение в команды Менеджера Сообщества | 2 | 0 |
| Публикации натыканы | 0 | 8,268 |
| Публикации удалены⁶ | 1,324 | 38,717 |
| Публикации заблокированы | 7 | 131 |
| Публикации восстановлены | 44 | 1,273 |
| Публикации разблокированы | 1 | 5 |
| Обработаны флаги вопросов⁵ | 1,127 | 6,741 |
| Вопросы закрыты | 921 | 11,263 |
| Вопросы отмечены флажками⁵ | 47 | 7,980 |
| Вопросы объединены | 2 | 0 |
| Вопросы перенесены | 1 | 7 |
| Вопросы защищены | 0 | 466 |
| Вопросы повторно открыты | 81 | 149 |
| Редакции отредактированы | 7 | 0 |
| Метки подсветки языка заданы | 7 | 0 |
| Синонимы меток созданы | 4 | 1 |
| Синонимы меток предложены | 3 | 2 |
| Метки объединены | 3 | 0 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁴: Очередь "Голоса закрытия" | 26 | 34,987 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁴: Очередь "Первые ответы" | 0 | 19,185 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁴: Очередь "Первые вопросы" | 0 | 42,569 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁴: Очередь "Запоздалые ответы" | 0 | 8,329 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁴: Очередь "Публикации низкого качества" | 0 | 42,931 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁴: Очередь "Голоса повторно открытия" | 16 | 10,079 |
| Рассмотрены задачи⁴: Очередь «Предлагаемые правки» | 11 | 18,851 |
| Пользователи забаненные на просмотр | 1 | 0 |
| Досрочно снятые блокировки пользователей | 1 | 0 |
| Связались пользователи | 69 | 0 |
| Удалено пользователей | 29 | 0 |
| Уничтожено пользователей³ | 32 | 0 |
| Заблокированно пользователей² | 30 | 15 |

#### Примечания

¹ «Сообщество» здесь относится как к [членству в Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users), так и к *без* [ромбам рядом с их именами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) и автоматизированным системам, иначе известным как [user #-1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² Система приостанавливает действия пользователей в трех случаях: когда пользователь создается повторно после того, как он был ранее заблокирован, когда пользователь создается повторно после того, как он был уничтожен за спам или злоупотребления, и когда в отношении учетной записи действует общесетевая блокировка.

³ "Уничтоженный" пользователь удаляется вместе со всем, что он разместил: вопросы, ответы, комментарии. [Обычно используется как целесообразный способ избавиться от спама.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ При этом учитывается каждый отправленный (не пропущенный) отзыв, поэтому 2 предлагаемых отзыва об изменениях, необходимых для утверждения изменения, будут считаться как 2, цель состоит в том, чтобы указать частоту действий модерации. Это также относится к флагам и.т.п.

⁵ Включает в себя флаги закрытия (но *не* закрытие или повторное открытие голосования). Сообщество может обрабатывать эти флаги, если хотя бы один человек проголосует за закрытие вопроса с пометкой закрытия.

⁶ Игнорируются многочисленные удаления, которые происходят автоматически в ответ на какое-то другое действие.

⁷ Сюда входят комментарии, удаленные их собственными авторами (которые также учитывают некоторое количество обработанных флажков комментариев).

#### Для дальнейшего чтения:

- Вы также можете проверить [этот отчет на других сайтах](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Или просмотреть [подробная информация о количестве закрытых и повторно открытых вопросов по всем сайтам](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)

Желаю всем счастливого 2023 года! ^_^